# C++: compiling function call to unrelated derived class, bug or feature?

Tags: c++, abstract-class, void-pointers

Fooling a bit around in C++, I stumbled across something which I believe is an error of both clang++ (6.0) and g++ (5.3): I am able to trick the compiler to call functions it should not be able to.

In short, I am declaring an abstract base class from which I derive two classes: a non-abstract and an abstract, which are related only via their common base class but have different functions. Instantiating the non-abstract base class and tricking the compiler to create a pointer of the abstract derived class pointing to the non-derived, I am able to call - via that pointer - a function of the original non-abstract class and the abstract class.

Minimal example, the two lines which give me a headache are at the bottom, separated by a comment line with stars:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

class MYBase {
public:
  virtual void fun1() = 0;
};

class MYDer1 : public MYBase {
public:
  ~MYDer1() { std::cout << "~MYDer1()\n"; }
  void fun1() { std::cout << "MYDer1 fun1\n"; }
};

class MYDer2 : public MYBase {
public:
  ~MYDer2() { std::cout << "~MYDer2()\n"; }
  void something2() { std::cout << "MYDer2 something2\n"; }
};


int main () {
  MYDer1 x1;

  // Good: cannot instantiate a 'MYDer2' as it is an abstract class
  //  due to unimplemented pure virtual method 'fun1' in 'MYDer2'
  //
  // MYDer2 x2;

  // Good, clang++ and g++ rightfully refuse to compile this:
  //
  //   auto * pd2 = static_cast<MYDer2 *>(&x1);

  // So let's be 'clever' and take a detour via 'void':
  auto * pd2 = static_cast<MYDer2 *>(static_cast<void *>(&x1));

  // Just to be sure the compiler got it right
  assert(typeid(pd2) == typeid(MYDer2 *));

  /***********************************************************/
  // There is no "fun1" declared in MYDer2
  // So why does this even compile?
  pd2->fun1();

  // And why does this execute correctly?
  pd2->something2();

  return 0;
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: FWIW `auto * pd2 = static_cast<MYDer2 *>(static_cast<void *>(&x1));` is clever but undefined behavior.  The compiler not warning you later is not something it really needs to do as you broke the contract.

Comment: "There is no "fun1" declared in MYDer2". No, but there's an accessible `fun1` declared in the direct base class `MYBase`.

Comment: @NathanOliver I do not think that this is the reason. What also compiles is this: `MYDer2 * pdn = nullptr; pdn->fun1()` (though it will obviously and rightfully crash).

Comment: @MSalters How it is accessible? MYBase has it declared as virtual, and there is no direct connection of MYDer2 to MYDer1, therefore MYDer2 should not be ending up being able to call fun1() of MYDer1.

Comment: @BaCh:  It's a `public` member in a `public` base class. `virtual` does not affect access, only `private/protected/public` does.

Answer (score 3):

It is undefined behavior so this time you shot yourself in the leg but missed. It is a programmer's responsibility to ensure that pointer being dereferenced really points to the object of specified type.

Comment: I am totally aware that the above is shooting myself in the foot style. What I really do not understand is why the compiler does not warn on `pd2->fun1();`

Comment: @BaCh UB in general occurs when programmer violates some language contract that simply could not be properly enforced by the compiler. So compiler does not have to warn about UBs at all.

Comment: would `MYDer2 * pdn = nullptr; pdn->fun1()` also violate a contract? (nullptr taken here for "any place in memory which could have a valid MYDer2 object).

Comment: @BaCh `nullptr` stands for "invalid pointer value" so dereferencing invalid pointer is contract violation as well (regardless of type of object it points to).

Answer (score 0):

This is undefined behavior because `x1` is of type `MYDer1` and you cast it by force to `MYDer2`. The code might not work because you are not really doing anything with function `something2`. Try to add a member variable to `MYDer2` and print it to see the problem.